# Why does the compiler generate code that writes the same stuff in the same memory location over and over again?

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, llvm-clang

I compiled the following code using `clang` and `gcc` and called both with `-O3`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void a(int n) {
  if (n == 0) return;

  printf("descending; a=%i\n", n);
  a(n-1);
}

int main() {
  a(5);
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the main function `gcc` generated (without NOPs at the end):

```
08048310 <main>:
 8048310:   55                      push   %ebp
 8048311:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048313:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 8048316:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
 8048319:   c7 44 24 04 05 00 00    movl   $0x5,0x4(%esp)
 8048320:   00 
 8048321:   c7 04 24 14 85 04 08    movl   $0x8048514,(%esp)
 8048328:   e8 c7 ff ff ff          call   80482f4 <printf@plt>
 804832d:   c7 44 24 04 04 00 00    movl   $0x4,0x4(%esp)
 8048334:   00 
 8048335:   c7 04 24 14 85 04 08    movl   $0x8048514,(%esp)
 804833c:   e8 b3 ff ff ff          call   80482f4 <printf@plt>
 8048341:   c7 44 24 04 03 00 00    movl   $0x3,0x4(%esp)
 8048348:   00 
 8048349:   c7 04 24 14 85 04 08    movl   $0x8048514,(%esp)
 8048350:   e8 9f ff ff ff          call   80482f4 <printf@plt>
 8048355:   c7 44 24 04 02 00 00    movl   $0x2,0x4(%esp)
 804835c:   00 
 804835d:   c7 04 24 14 85 04 08    movl   $0x8048514,(%esp)
 8048364:   e8 8b ff ff ff          call   80482f4 <printf@plt>
 8048369:   c7 44 24 04 01 00 00    movl   $0x1,0x4(%esp)
 8048370:   00 
 8048371:   c7 04 24 14 85 04 08    movl   $0x8048514,(%esp)
 8048378:   e8 77 ff ff ff          call   80482f4 <printf@plt>
 804837d:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 804837f:   c9                      leave  
 8048380:   c3                      ret
```

And here's the one from `clang`:

```
080483d0 <main>:
 80483d0:   55                      push   %ebp
 80483d1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80483d3:   56                      push   %esi
 80483d4:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
 80483d7:   be 05 00 00 00          mov    $0x5,%esi
 80483dc:   8d 74 26 00             lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
 80483e0:   89 74 24 04             mov    %esi,0x4(%esp)
 80483e4:   c7 04 24 e0 84 04 08    movl   $0x80484e0,(%esp)
 80483eb:   e8 04 ff ff ff          call   80482f4 <printf@plt>
 80483f0:   4e                      dec    %esi
 80483f1:   75 ed                   jne    80483e0 <main+0x10>
 80483f3:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 80483f5:   83 c4 0c                add    $0xc,%esp
 80483f8:   5e                      pop    %esi
 80483f9:   5d                      pop    %ebp
 80483fa:   c3                      ret
```

My question is: Is there a good reason why they both generate code that writes the address of the static string on the stack over and over again? For example, why doesn't the code `clang` generates look like this instead?

```
080483d0 <main>:
 80483d0:   55                      push   %ebp
 80483d1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80483d3:   56                      push   %esi
 80483d4:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
 80483d7:   be 05 00 00 00          mov    $0x5,%esi
 80483dc:   8d 74 26 00             lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
 80483e0:   c7 04 24 e0 84 04 08    movl   $0x80484e0,(%esp)
 80483e7:   89 74 24 04             mov    %esi,0x4(%esp)
 80483eb:   e8 04 ff ff ff          call   80482f4 <printf@plt>
 80483f0:   4e                      dec    %esi
 80483f1:   xx xx                   jne    80483e7 <main+0x17>
 80483f3:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 80483f5:   83 c4 0c                add    $0xc,%esp
 80483f8:   5e                      pop    %esi
 80483f9:   5d                      pop    %ebp
 80483fa:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: i guess it is because the function is allowed to modifiy the value in the stack. for example if printf was `printf(char *c,int i){c=null;}`

Comment: Your code is written with recursion. Clang turns it into a loop; GCC unrolls it. Neither seem to do quite as much hoisting as you would hope.

Comment: @Gir: ah, that sounds plausible

Comment: @EricPostpischil: `printf()` isn't allowed to modify the memory to which the pointer points but that doesn't protect the memory area where the pointer itself is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Mac OS X Application Binary Interface, the parameters passed on the stack may be modified by the called routine. So, where the calling routine puts the address of the format string on the stack, the called routine is allowed to write to that place on the stack. (It is not permitted generally to write to higher [earlier] locations on the stack.) Therefore, the calling routine cannot know that, after the called routine returns, the parameters the calling routine wrote to the stack are unchanged.

This is a convenience for routines that might modify their arguments while using them to perform calculations. E.g., you could have code such as:

```
int foo(int x)
{
    x *= x;
    return x+3;
}
```

Obviously, for code this simple, the compiler would not actually need to store the product in x in order to finish computing the return value. However, with more complicated routines, you can see where the compiler might decide to store a value to x.

As an ABI design issue, you could wonder whether it might be better to prohibit the called routine from using this space, so that the caller could rely on the values not changing. However, using a parameter repeatedly this way is not hugely common, and the cost of writing a new copy is tiny.

Also note that only the **address** of the format string, which was written to the stack, may be changed. C semantics require that the **contents** of the format string remain unchanged by the called routine, since it is const char.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is how the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) defines ownership of a "stack frame." In a nutshell, as soon as you call a function, that function gets ownership of the current stack frame (which includes the parameters, return address and any local variables).

It can do *anything* with it. There is no guarantee whatsoever that `printf()` keeps anything in the stack frame intact. While it's bad practice to do so, functions can do this and I have written code which messes with the stack (for example in a C interpreter, written in C, which could call any compiled function, especially `printf()`).

So there is no guarantee that the pointer to the static string is still on the stack when `printf()` returns. Note that the compiler can't assume that `printf()` will behave because you could link against a different C runtime with a custom implementation of `printf()`.

Try to call a function where GCC can see the source code. For these, it might optimize the stack further.

**[EDIT]** Maybe a different example makes this easier to understand. In some cases, GCC optimizes function argument passing. Instead of pushing them on the stack, they will be passed in CPU registers. Let's assume that it uses `%eax` for this. If the arguments were owned by the calling function, the called function would not be allowed to modify `%eax`.

Comment: This not defined by C. Assembly language semantics are not addressed by the C standard.

Comment: The optimizer may not choose whether to pass arguments in registers or on the stack (except for static functions). Argument passing is defined by the application binary interface for the target platform, and externally visible functions must comply with the interface (so that they can be called from languages other than C). If the compiler uses a different ABI for static functions (not externally visible), then whether the register belongs to the called routine or the calling routine is up to the compiler and is not addressed in any way by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Unless the callee is static or you're doing LTO, right?

Comment: @thejh: Yes, link-time optimization would also permit a choice of where to pass arguments.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Well, it's defined by the ABI. Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

The short problem is function calls. The C compiler can't really make any guarantees about what happens in a function call (unless it's one of the C built-ins, such as `strlen`). So, it has to not optimise around them. Consider:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
val = 5;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

If the compiler inferred that the write to val was independent of the call to `pthread_mutex_lock`, then it could push it before the lock, and mass chaos would ensue.

The compiler has to assume that the last write before a function call has to be done. If the write occurs inside a block of code where it knows exactly what's going on (i.e., no function calls or only built-ins), then it can optimise as it pleases and pull out unneeded writes.

There's no way for the compiler to infer whether a function has access to a variable (at least not without solving the halting problem). Another function might have the address set up before or use something like `dlsym` to figure out the address of something it its own binary, even if that symbol is not exported.